# Default argument for template not working

Tags: c++, templates, using-declaration

I have a chain of nested templated using declarations. It looks something like this:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C, typename D>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : value{0} {};

    template <typename AC, typename BC, typename CC, typename DC>
    Foo(const Foo<AC, BC, CC, DC>& rhs) : value{rhs.value} {}

    template <typename AC, typename BC, typename CC, typename DC>
    Foo& operator=(const Foo<AC, BC, CC, DC>& rhs) {
        value = rhs.value;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename F>
    F convertTo() {
        return F(*this);
    }

    C value;
};

template <typename ThingC, typename ThingD>
using Bar = Foo<int, float, ThingC, ThingD>;

template <typename ThingD = long double>
using Bif = Bar<char, ThingD>;
```

The following gives me trouble:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Bif bifDefault;
    Bif<long> bifLong;

    Bif<unsigned> bifUnsigned = bifDefault.convertTo<Bif<unsigned>>();
    Bif<long double> bifLongDouble = bifLong.convertTo<Bif>(); // ERROR...
    // expected a type, got 'Bif'
}
```

I also get an error at the `F convertTo` line : `template argument deduction/substitution failed`.

And the weirdest error, at the ERROR line:

```
no instance of function template "Foo<A, B, C, D>::convertTo [ with A=int, B=float, C=char, D=long int]" matches the argument list
```

**D=long int**! What's going on here? Changing it to just double doesn't work either. Clearly, the default template argument is propagating through to the function, but it's doing it *wrong* for long double, and doesn't work even when it does get the type correct.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Bif` isn't a type, it's a `template`d type.  You're getting away with it when you declare `bifDefault` because of [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), but it doesn't apply when you call `convertTo` (you're not passing a non-type `template` parameter).  The code compiles as expected when replaced with `bifLong.convertTo<Bif<>>()`.